# DevExpress: How to make a Devexpress Combo box shows only non selected items?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I created a Combo box using Devexpress ASP.Net MVC. I fill the combo box from a database. My question is How to make a Devexpress Combo box shows only non selected items?

So suppose

- I have a combo box that has the following values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- I selected value (1)
- when I add a new row and open the combo box, it should show (2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: Seems you want to use `GridView` with cascading `ComboBox`, which points to same data source but only showing non-selected items on next (added?) rows. Can you show current code you have to accomplish given objectives?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes I do use a GridView, but I need to show only the non selected values in the same filed but in a new row. As the scenario had been written in description.

Comment: I need to know how you create `GridView` layout with `ComboBox` inside it first, and what DB model/viewmodel involved - AFAIK you can use `e.customArgs` to define values which already used as callback argument & use query to put them out of list.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I use the basic to create it so to create the combo box I do V.DataSource = Path.to.controller.getValue();. In getValue() I wrote a simple LINQ. Whatever your solution, please put your answer and I can discuss it with you.

Comment: I think `ComboBox` or `ComboBoxFor` uses `BindList` method linked to `IEnumerable` instead of `DataSource` property, I'm curious are you in the right way using DX MVC extensions? Putting some code for both `GridView` & `ComboBox(For)` can help yourself identify the problem.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes I did all of that. getValue() is a IEnumerable action inside the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter data source of combo-box using LINQ. Remove earlier selected items from data source.When you add a new row, on callback of control you can filter out this data source.